# Saving a List to the database as multiple rows

Tags: django

I have a list that is derived from check box selections defined as the following:

```
checkedlist = request.GET.getlist('report_id')
```

This list gets POSTed to a submitted view.

```
def submitted(request):

    owner = User.objects.get (formattedusername=request.user.formattedusername)
    requestsave = QVFormAccessRequest(ntname_id = owner.formattedusername, first_name = owner.first_name, last_name = owner.last_name, coid = owner.coid, facility = owner.facility, title = owner.title
                                      ,report_id = request.POST.getlist('report_id'))

    requestsave.save()
```

The problem is that when it tries to save to the database my field is defined as an int which is correct.  I want my report_id for the list to be stored on multiple lines in my database like the following:

```
user information report_id
user1234         1
user1234         2
user1234         3
user1234         4
```

In the current save it's trying to post the list to the report_id how would I break it into multiple rows as shown above? I get the following error:

```
TypeError at /account/submitted/
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about

```
my_list = request.POST.getlist('report_id')
for i in my_list
    requestsave = QVFormAccessRequest(ntname_id = owner.formattedusername, first_name = owner.first_name, last_name = owner.last_name, coid = owner.coid, facility = owner.facility, title = owner.title, report_id = i)
    requestsave.save()
```